# Pagination Code Maxes Out at Six Pages In Selection Menu (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I've added pagination to my WordPress blog with code. It works fine up to a point. The code I'm using was provided from here:

http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/

When I add it, the menu shows up at the bottom and it functions fine but it maxes out at 6 pages in the menu. It has generated 9 pages (because that's the exact amount of content I have at the moment) and continues to generate new pages but doesn't update on the menu at the bottom. It only has six pages there. Here is the exact code I have in my functions.php (should be the same as the link I posted):

```
/* PAGINATION */
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
/*END PAGINATION*/
```

And then it's called like this:

```
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
    pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything that would explain the problem you're running into, but here's a very basic Pagination script of my own making I think might help:

```
global $paged;
$curpage = $paged ? $paged : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    //'category_name' => 'your_category_name' /*If needed*/
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
    <div class="postBlock"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    echo '<div id="wp_pagination">';
    echo '<a class="first page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(1).'">&laquo;</a>';
    echo '<a class="previous page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage-1 > 0 ? $curpage-1 : 1)).'">&lsaquo;</a>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$query->max_num_pages;$i++)
        echo '<a class="'.($active = $i == $curpage ? 'active ' : '').'page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($i).'">'.$i.'</a>';
    echo '<a class="next page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link(($curpage+1 <= $query->max_num_pages ? $curpage+1 : $query->max_num_pages)).'">&rsaquo;</a>';
    echo '<a class="last page button" href="'.get_pagenum_link($query->max_num_pages).'">&raquo;</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```